# Split combined arabic characters in individual characters

Tags: java, c#, arabic

I'm trying to convert "combined arabic characters" (like ﻼ ) in the different individual characters that compose that "combined" character (e.g. ﻝ ا). I wasnt able to do this in JAVA or C#, because I need split the complete list of characters.

In C# i'm trying to get the Unicode character, convert it to Windows-1256 waiting to get 2 o 3 bytes that are the individual characters and that combined character uses, but I wasnt able to do this.

```
String unicodeWord = (char)sc;
byte[] arabicBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(unicodeWord);
```

but the result is always ?.

Can you help me with this? I have not problem to use either java or c#.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Important note: you aren't after *bytes* here; you are after *characters* - hence this is not an *encoding* concern, but a *normalization* concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = "ﻼ";
string normalized = input.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC);
```

Note that there are [different normalization forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.normalizationform.aspx) with different results; `FormKC` results in ل and ا